Formatted strings with arguments in Xcode 15 String Catalogs
How can I use a formatted string with arguments in Xcode 15's string catalogs?
For example, if my string is showing a percentage "\() %%" (example rendering: "25 %") and I've given it a key of my_string in the catalog, how can I fill in the numeric argument when using the string?

String(format: String(localized: "my_string"), String(99))  // rendered as "99 %"

Note that in this particular example the percent sign needs to be escaped using %% and numbers need to be wrapped with the string initializer (otherwise very bad things will happen).

Aside: this is probably not the best way to format percentages. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/preparing-dates-numbers-with-formatters
